# Package local jar classes in kotlin jvm jar with gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I'm using the Kotlin jvm Gradle plugin to build and publish a Java/JVM jar. With just the Kotlin source, everything works. However, this particular project references some local jars as dependencies. I would like to grab the class files from those local jars and include them in my jar file for publishing.

I've found a few examples but they're all fairly old, or use groovy, or are building a separate jar that's not being published.

This is specifically for a gradle plugin, but I assume it would be the same for any JVM build. The relevant part of the `build.gradle.kts` is as follows:

```kotlin
plugins {
  id("java-gradle-plugin")
  kotlin("jvm")
}

dependencies {
  implementation(kotlin("gradle-plugin-api"))
  implementation(fileTree("lib") { include("*.jar") })
}
```

There are jar files in the lib folder, and I'd just like to pull the classes from those files into the jar we're going to publish with this plugin (the source jars come from open source with a compatible license, but they're not published anywhere we can reference from gradle).

To preempt "why don't you do ___" answers, this is to get something out the door quickly. If this is the route we're taking long term, we'll try to collect and build the source from the dependency projects, but it's a complex config.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the [Shadow plugin for Gradle](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/).

Comment: I think you're right, looking at the docs. Thanks!